# Discord.js bot error with repeated message that seemingly comes from nowhere

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, quick.db

I am getting a problem where when i try to 1v1 someone, it continues to say "Looks like the user you are trying to 1v1 is passive!"

This is using the latest version of quick db and discord js.

I am guessing this is just a silly mistake i made when typing something in. If so, let me know!

Here is my 1v1request code:

```
const db = require("quick.db");
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const fs = require('fs');
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js')
const talkedRecently = new Set();

module.exports = {
  name: '1v1request',
  description: 'request someone to have a 1v1 ',
  execute(message, args, client) {

    if (talkedRecently.has(message.author.id)) {
      message.reply("Wait 1 day before being able to use this command again.");
    } else {

      const userto1v1 = message.mentions.users.first()

      if (!userto1v1) {
        message.channel.send('Make sure to specify a user!')
      } else {

        let userto1v1passive = db.get(`passive_${message.guild.id}_${userto1v1.id}`)

        if (userto1v1passive = 1) {

          message.channel.send("Looks like the user you are trying to 1v1 is passive!")

        } else {

          let amipassive = db.get(`passive_${message.guld.id}_${message.author.id}`)

          if (amipassive = 1) {

            message.channel.send("You are on passive!")

          } else {

            let trophies = db.get(`trophies_${message.guild.id}_${message.author.id}`)

            let trophies1 = db.get(`trophies_${message.guild.id}_${userto1v1.id}`)

            if (trophies < trophies1) {

              let trophiestobelost = (trophies1 - trophies) + 10

              client.channels.cache.get('944400414642688000').send(`**New 1v1 Request** - ${message.author} wishes to 1v1 ${userto1v1}! ${userto1v1} has 2 days to respond before they lose ${trophiestobelost} trophies!`);
              talkedRecently.add(message.author.id);
              setTimeout(() => {
                talkedRecently.delete(message.author.id);
              }, 86400000);

            } else {
              message.channel.send("You can't 1v1 someone with less or equal trophies than you!")
            }

          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and here is my passive command code.

```
const db = require("quick.db");
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const fs = require('fs');
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js')
const talkedRecently = new Set();

module.exports = {
  name: 'passive',
  description: 'turn on passive',
  execute(message, args, client) {

    if (talkedRecently.has(message.author.id)) {
      message.reply("Wait 2 days before being able to use this command again.");
    } else {

      let filter = m => m.author.id === message.author.id
      message.channel.send(`Would you like to enable or disable passive? \`ENABLE\` / \`DISABLE\``).then(() => {
        message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, {
          max: 1,
          time: 30000,
          errors: ['time']
        })
          .then(message => {
            message = message.first()
            if (message.content.toUpperCase() == 'ENABLE' || message.content.toUpperCase() == 'E') {

              db.set(`passive_${message.guild.id}_${message.author.id}`, 1)
              message.channel.send('Passive Enabled. Disabling passive will let you re-enable passive in 2 days. Passive will be automatically removed after 2 days.')

              setTimeout(() => {
                db.set(`passive_${message.guild.id}_${message.author.id}`, 0)
              }, 172800000);

            } else if (message.content.toUpperCase() == 'DISABLE' || message.content.toUpperCase() == 'D') {

              db.set(`passive_${message.guild.id}_${message.author.id}`, 0)

              message.channel.send('Succesfully disabled. You can use this command again in 2 days.')

              talkedRecently.add(message.author.id);
              setTimeout(() => {
                talkedRecently.delete(message.author.id);
              }, 172800000);

            } else {
              message.channel.send(`Invalid Response.`)
            }
          })
          .catch(collected => {
            message.channel.send('Timeout. Did not answer in time.');
          });
      })
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: If my answer worked, make sure to mark it as the best answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong operator. You would need to use `==` instead of `=`. Read more about these operators [here](https://www.guru99.com/difference-equality-strict-operator-javascript.html). Your fixed code would look something like this:

```js
const db = require('quick.db');
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const fs = require('fs');
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
const talkedRecently = new Set();

module.exports = {
    name: '1v1request',
    description: 'request someone to have a 1v1 ',
    execute(message, args, client) {
        if (talkedRecently.has(message.author.id)) {
            message.reply('Wait 1 day before being able to use this command again.');
        } else {
            const userto1v1 = message.mentions.users.first();

            if (!userto1v1) {
                message.channel.send('Make sure to specify a user!');
            } else {
                let userto1v1passive = db.get(`passive_${message.guild.id}_${userto1v1.id}`);

                if (userto1v1passive == 1) {
                    message.channel.send('Looks like the user you are trying to 1v1 is passive!');
                } else {
                    let amipassive = db.get(`passive_${message.guld.id}_${message.author.id}`);

                    if (amipassive == 1) {
                        message.channel.send('You are on passive!');
                    } else {
                        let trophies = db.get(`trophies_${message.guild.id}_${message.author.id}`);
                        let trophies1 = db.get(`trophies_${message.guild.id}_${userto1v1.id}`);

                        if (trophies < trophies1) {
                            let trophiestobelost = (trophies1 - trophies) + 10;
                            client.channels.cache.get('944400414642688000').send(`**New 1v1 Request** - ${message.author} wishes to 1v1 ${userto1v1}! ${userto1v1} has 2 days to respond before they lose ${trophiestobelost} trophies!`);
                            talkedRecently.add(message.author.id);
                            setTimeout(() => {
                                talkedRecently.delete(message.author.id);
                            }, 86400000);
                        } else {
                            message.channel.send('You can\'t 1v1 someone with less or equal trophies than you!');
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Hoped this helped!**

Comment: Thanks for the help :))
I gotta look more into this == and === sign thing